# Как привязать текст к канвасу? Unity

Tags: unity3d

Нужно чтобы при изменении размера канваса сам текст оставался на той же позиции ( Если был в нижнем правом углу - то в нем и должен оставаться )
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

на сколько я понимаю вопрос - необходимо

1. разместить текст в обьекте канваса
2. отцентровать его по горизонтали и вертикали относительно обьекта текста
3. в RectTransform задать пивот поинт в центр
4. Указать все необходимые анкоры на обьекту текста через инспектор